# How do I add a UI Button to change view layer to a specific view layer

Tags: python, interface, customization

I'd like to be able to change the view layer of my scene via UI buttons. I currently have rendering of different layers working on different buttons, but I keep running into errors or having it simply not work while trying to change the view layer via buttons.
[image]

```
#Skeleton View Layer Button (This doesn't work)
    row = layout.row()
    row.scale_y = 1.0
    row.operator("scene.viewlayer", text="View Skeleton", icon="FILE_IMAGE") = "SkeleLayer"
#Skeleton Render Layer Button
    row = layout.row()
    row.scale_y = 2.0
    row.operator("render.render", text="Render Skeleton", icon="FILE_IMAGE").layer="SkeleLayer"
```

Comment: As the error states, you have made a syntax error: Your code is attempting to assign a string value to a function call when it is not possible. To simplify, here is some simple code with the same problem: print(“Cheese”) = 42

Comment: I'm aware of that, a simple googling lets me know the syntax problem, but I don't know the correct way to create and assign the function to the button in blender and that's what I'm asking for help with.